# how to add unsafe keyword in web based asp.net application c#

Tags: asp.net, unsafe

Hi
how i can use unsafe keyword in web based application for pointers?
In windows application we have setting in properties section of project under build tag we can check allow unsafe code checkbox, but in web based application  how to allow unsafe code or any other in replacement of unsafe code (Pointer)
asp.net c#

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If this is a web application you can simply go to the properties of the project and allow unsafe code as you would do in any standard class library. If it is a web site you could try putting the following in your web.config:

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler 
            language="c#;cs;csharp" 
            extension=".cs" 
            compilerOptions="/unsafe"
            type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```