# Unable to Publish WCF Service with Unsafe code in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, publishing, unsafe-pointers

This might be same problem as mentioned in the following link
[Publish web application with unsafe code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567197/asp-net-publish-web-application-with-unsafe-code)

I have a wcf service with a block of Unsafe code. 
I have Allowed Unsafe Code in My Project properties. 
The Application is able build properly where as it is unable to publish the project.
It Says **Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe error** during the publishing the project. and finally says build failed.

I feel its strange because it is able build the project successfully but failed in publishing.

I have tried the following help link but not worked for me.

[how to add unsafe keyword in web based asp.net application c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867613/how-to-add-unsafe-keyword-in-web-based-asp-net-application-c-sharp)

Comment: Publish typically works with release builds. Does your release build compile?

Comment: Yes I see the dlls after I build the project in bin folder

Answer (score 1):

It seems when you publish it ignores the project setting of unsafe, so you need to manually open your .CSPROJ file and include:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

That solved it for me.

Googled this issue but could not find anything. Checked the *.targets files for "unsafe" which led me to the "AllowUnsafeBlocks" tag. Definately a bug.