# Visual Studio C# web app - How to get unsafe keyword for pointers

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I'm trying to allow access to the `unsafe` access modifier so I can take advantage of pointers to store memory addresses in my ASP.NET C# Web Forms Site. I've read plenty of documentation saying there is a checkbox you can check to allow `unsafe` code by going to Project > Properties > Build. An image of that window is something like this:

[image: Unsafe checkbox]

The problem is, my Project Properties window doesn't look anything like that or have that option. Mine looks like this:

[image: My Window]

When I go to Debug > website_name Properties (instead of Project Properties), I actually do have a `Build` tab, but it doesn't have a checkbox for unsafe code either. It looks like this:

[image: My Window]

So that eliminates my possibilities of using any checkbox - maybe it doesn't come with web apps or wasn't part of my installation? Some articles say they do come in web-based apps, but I think they are only for Windows (WPF) and console apps as stated in this article: [how to add unsafe keyword in web based asp.net application c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867613/how-to-add-unsafe-keyword-in-web-based-asp-net-application-c-sharp). Either way, that left me with a couple other options, and they were to allow /unsafe to the compiler explicitly. One is to go the Web.config file and add the following lines:

```
<system.codedom>
   <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" compilerOptions="/unsafe" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
   </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

That hasn't worked. Most of the docs I found for the Web.config compilers came back in years like 2010 and 2011 - like in the one I listed above, so they had version 2.0.0.0. This code can easily have changed since then, and as you can see in my last picture, my target framework is 4.5.2, so I used version 4.0.0.0, but still no luck. One last explicit way of trying to allow the `unsafe` keyword is by entering in the following command in the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt:

```
csc /unsafe Your_Web_Form.aspx
```

That command gave me an error for each line of my .aspx file. I would really appreciate help on this issue, and I'm sure it could help many others who have recently had this problem and are looking for more recent documentation.

Comment: Any chance you stop using "web site" template ("This template does not produce a project file and has limited MSBuild support") and switch to normal "ASP.Net Web Application" that actually use projects?

Comment: You could edit your `.csproj` file. Under `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration) [...]`, add node `<AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>`

Comment: @user3670011 ??? OP does not have project files... otherwise they would be able to use project properties just fine.

Comment: Alexei Levenkov - thank you, it worked! I remember now I used a Web Forms Site template for my solution, and now I see that site solutions are not projects but Web Application templates are. The window I was looking for came up.

Comment: What do you need pointers for in a Web Forms app?

Comment: lol it's funny you ask. There's no particular reason, I'm just using it as a unique module to show the user what memory address a string is stored in by converting it to an integer, along with the hash codes for that string, like MD5, SHA1, and SHA256 checksums.